# Remove special character and substring inside

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have a string.

```
s <- "X[,1]>2 & M[,1]<2 & G[,4]>3"
```

I want to remove this substring  `[...Anything..]`  from "`s`"

As result i want to get  `"X>2 & M<2 & G>3"`

How can I remove these substrings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gsub` :

```
s <- "X[,1]>2 & M[,1]<2 & G[,4]>3"
gsub('\\[.*?\\]', '', s)
#[1] "X>2 & M<2 & G>3"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_remove_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(s, "\\[.*\\]")
```

#### data

```
s <- "X[,1]>2 & M[,1]<2 & G[,4]>3"
```